# How to run cql commands from a client Windows computer ?

Tags: cassandra

Our organization has a Cassandra on Linux cluster. I have a userid and password. I connect to this cluster using `datastax` with Java. However, there are limitation, for example I cannot run `describe` because this is a `cql` extention. I would like to run `cql` in a command prompt. How can i do this? What do I need to install on my Windows 10 computer to be able to connect to that remote Cassandra cluster?

(I cannot SSH to that cluster )

Comment: Datastax DevCenter should work... OR download cassandra on your machine and use cqlsh in it to connect to remote cluster...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the Cassandra binaries and install python in order to run cqlsh.

Try using this [one](https://www.edureka.co/blog/how-to-open-cqlsh-of-cassandra-installed-on-windows/) and don't forget to change the ip and port to whatever suits you.